# Object is possibly 'null' con document.getElementById('product-detail-images').getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: angular

Buenas estoy trabajando en Angular universal y tengo la siguiente función

```
private validateBox() {
    const divHeight: any = document.getElementById('product-detail-images').getBoundingClientRect();
    if (divHeight) {
        if (divHeight.top > -2491) {
            this.isAbsolute = false;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        } else {
            this.isAbsolute = true;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que `document.getElementById('product-detail-images').getBoundingClientRect()` me da error en consola.
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error de compilación, porque no estás comprobando si el elemento existe o no, pero tienes una comprobación sobre si la altura es 0 o no. Deberías comprobarlo así:

```
private validateBox() {
    const divHeight: any = document.getElementById('product-detail-images')!.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (divHeight.top > -2491) {
            this.isAbsolute = false;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        } else {
            this.isAbsolute = true;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

El símbolo de admiración es el operador "check not null", si la llamada a `document.getElementById` es `null`, no provocará un error sino que hará que div valga `null`

Comment: Me sirvió de mucha ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que seguramente tienes activado en tu fichero tsconfig el flag `strict null checks`. Esto es una feature para evitar errores en runtime.

```
private validateBox() {
    const div: Element | null = document.getElementById('product-detail-images');
    if (div) {
        const divHeight: any = document.getElementById('product-detail-images').getBoundingClientRect();
        if (divHeight.top > -2491) {
            this.isAbsolute = false;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        } else {
            this.isAbsolute = true;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        }
    }
}
```